# Multiple HTML tables have different column widths when using identical colgroups

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several HTML tables on a page using the following layout:

```
H2 Header
Table
H2 Header
Table
H2 Header
Table
```

All tables should be 100% width with 3 columns of 50%, 30% and 20% width.  I have used the same CSS for each table to define the column widths.  I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.0 via NuGet; the `table` and `table-hover` classes are Bootstrap classes.

When the page loads, each table has a different page width.  This is despite the fact there is a CSS style in *bootstrap.css* which states `.table { width: 100% }`.  It is appearing to use the content of the columns to set the table width rather than the CSS style.

Am I missing something obvious or doing something wrong?  Do I need to explicitly set the tables to be 100%?

**CSS**

```
.columnA {
    width: 50%;
}

.columnB {
    width: 30%;
}

.columnC {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Duplicated several times -->
<h2>Header</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnA" />
        <col class="columnB" />
        <col class="columnC" />
    </colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        <tr>
        <!-- More rows -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Site Title</td>
            <td>http://web-address.url</td>
            <td>A description of the site</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you need the classes `table` and `table-hover` on a `table` element? Use `table { /* styles */ }` and `table:hover { /* styles */ }` and save yourself a headache.

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce the issue you are describing. I’ve pasted it in a demo here: http://jsbin.com/zubova/3/edit Please make modifications to that and give us the link back when the issue is visible.

Comment: I have updated the question to be a bit clearer about the issue I am facing.  @Zaqx - I appreciate I can manually write the styles but seeing as Bootstrap does it for me I'd rather use those.  Thanks for the sample but it does not set the table width (which Bootstrap does), and with no content they will be the same width anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modifies the table to accommodate all the cells content thats why your tables look different.

Try using the grid layout as defined in the bootstrap documentation for your table

[Bootstrap Grid Layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

For Example,

Instead of using this for width

```
<col class="columnA" />
<col class="columnB" />
<col class="columnC" />
```

you could use

```
<col class="col-md-6" />
<col class="col-md-4" />
<col class="col-md-2" />
```

Comment: Many thanks but that is overkill for what I need - just a table for tabulated data, not a grid.  :)